# How can I get rid of the brackets in a scala DSL expression?

Tags: scala, dsl

I'd like to be able to get rid of the brackets/parentheses in the following expression in my DSL:

`substitute ("hello {0}" using "world")`

The rest of the code looks like this:

```
class Rule(format: String) {
  def using(arggs: String*): Rule = { /* save the args */ return this }
  def execute() = { /* substitute params */ }
}

def substitute(rule: Rule) = rule.execute()
implicit def makeRule(format: String) = new Rule(format)
```

I've tried the apply() method but I don't think I can do it that way. Is there some scala magic out there I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala has it's own equivalent of the iamb / iambic meter (if you will) when you want to omit the `.` and the `(` ... `)`:

*target* (skipped `.`) *method* (skipped `(`) *singleArgument* (skipped `)`)

The *singleArgument* is optional.

Every dotless, parenless DSL-ish thing has to fit this pattern. It's why Scala internal DSLs are so often so stilted.

Comment: thanks but I knew that, that's what I've used inside the brackets. It's the outer brackets I'd like to get rid of somehow.

Comment: And that's the point. You can't 'cause it will change the parse in a completely breaking way. The best you can do is "re-phrase" your DSL so it conforms to the Scala dotless, parenthesis-free grammar.

Answer (score 2):

Not an exact solution for your case (@RandallSchulz is absolutely right), but you may use a two-word approach:

```
class RuleHelper(val txt: String) {
  def using(arggs: String*): RuleHelper = { /* save the args */ return this }
  def execute() = { /* substitute params */ }
}

object substitute {
  def in(txt: String) = new RuleHelper(txt)
}

substitute in "hello {0}" using "world"
```

It's not as beautiful as you would like, but I think it reduces the accidental complexity.